# Must Python script define a function as main?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

Must/should a Python script have a `main()` function? For example is it ok to replace

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

with

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  entryPoint()
```

(or some other meaningful name)

Comment: Yes. That bit of magic just stops your main function from being run when your script is imported. This just says "If I'm the main script, call this function".

Comment: @MorganThrapp: Are you answering the question in the title or the body?  Because they are contradictory.  ;)

Comment: Oops, didn't even notice that. I was answering the question about if it's okay to rename `main()`

Answer (score 10):

Using a function named `main()` is just a convention. You can give it any name you want to.

Testing for the module name is *just a nice trick* to prevent code running when your code is not being executed as the `__main__` module (i.e. not when imported as the script Python started with, but imported as a module). You can run any code you like under that `if` test.

Using a function in that case helps keep the global namespace of your module uncluttered by shunting names into a local namespace instead. Naming that function `main()` is commonplace, but not a requirement.

Comment: Actually it's a trick to _make_ the code run (not prevent it) when the script is executed as the `__main__` module.

Comment: @martineau: no, all code at the global level runs when a module is imported (be it run directly as a script or because it was imported indirectly). The `if __name__` test then *disables* the code when you are not running it directly as a script. I see that my text got the two muddled up, fixed that.

Answer (score 7):

No, a Python script doesn't have to have a `main()` function. It is just following conventions because the function that you put under the `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement is the function that really does all of the work for your script, so it is the main function. If there really is function name that would make the program easier to read and clearer, then you can instead use that function name.

In fact, you don't even *need* the `if __name__ == '__main__':` part, but it is a good practice, not just a convention. It will just prevent the `main()` function or whatever else you would like to call it from running when you import the file as a module. If you won't be importing the script, you *probably* don't need it, but it is still a good practice. For more on that and why it does what it does, see [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)